# Checking identical files in Linux and deleting according to location

Tags: deduplication

I use fdupes to find and delete identical files.

But I want to be able to say something like this ...

- find all the files that are duplicate in directory A or its subdirectories
- if there's a duplicated file in subdirs B and C then always delete the file in B

In other words, keep all the files in C that are not already in B. And note that the directory structures are not the same so rsync isn't useful here.

I don't think fdupes offers this functionality. I have to manually choose which to delete / keep for each pair.

So I was thinking of writing a quick Python script to do the same thing. But is there a quick system command I can call from Python which can give me some kind of unique id for each file that's a reliable way of seeing if two files are identical. I'm thinking of something that doesn't involve me loading the files into python and hashing their contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a hash is the only fast way to know if multipule files match, but you can speed it up by only comparing files of the same size, also select a fast hash like md5 if no one is trying for collisions... this is done for you with git/zfs/etc

Or just

```
fdupes -r A B | grep B | xargs -I {} rm "{}"
```